# Template member function with stl

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following existing code snippet in MyQueue.h

```
class MyQueue {
 struct A {
  explicit A(ValType init){
 }
 ValType memberA;
 };
 struct B {
  explicit B {...}
  std::list<A> listofA; 
 };
 std::unordered_map<std::string, B> myMap;
};
```

ValType is a know class type defined in a different file.

#### GOAL

I need to templatize Valtype, meaning struct A constructor (or anywhere Valtype is used) can be Valtype or Valtype2.

My Questions are as follows

1. Does the whole class MyQueue need to be a template class or can the relevant member variables and member function be templatized like I have below. What are the general rules to decide this?
2. Can stl container be of template type? ex `std::unordered_map<std::string, B<T>> myMap;` `std::list<A<T>> listofA;`

This class has a cpp file with definitions of class member functions that use A, B and myMap.

```
class MyQueue {
 template <class T>
 struct A {
  explicit A(T init){
 }
 T memberA;
 };

 struct B {
  explicit B {...}
  template <class T>
  std::list<A<T>> listofA; 
 };
 template <class T>
 std::unordered_map<std::string, B<T>> myMap;
};
```

Comment: No, you cannot put templates on member varibles like that. Why wouldn't you put it on the outer class? It would be the easiest solution

Comment: Thinking twice. If valtype is know, why template at all? Why can't you access it. Don't add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @JHBonarius I want to refactor such that Valtype or Valtype1 should work, hence template

Comment: Should both work at the same time? You know `MyQueue<Valtype>` and `MyQueue<Valtype2>` will be different types, right? They will not be compatible. Why not write an overload set?

Comment: @JHBonarius when I use a put template on the outer class, will I use` std::list<A<T>> listofA;` or regular  `std::list<A> listofA;`

Comment: MyQueue<Valtype> and MyQueue<Valtype2> needn't work at the same time.

Comment: You learn by trying 

Answer (score 0):

I made the class a template class

```
template<class TypeName>
class MyQueue {
};
```

For defining the member functions, I moved definitions from MyQueue.cpp to newly created MyQueue-inl.h which I include at the end of MyQueue.h